# How to copy item of char of array at specific index to anther array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

Suppose there are two arrays e.g

```
char arr1[10]="12345";
char arr2[4][4]={"0","-1"};
```

I want to copy item at index 1 in arr1 into arr2 at index 1. How can i do this ?  I have tried this

```
strcpy(arr2[1],arr1[1])
```

But i am not able to copy.

Comment: Your code is not valid in Java.

Comment: What is the "functon" `str`?

Comment: perhaps he meant strcpy.

Comment: In java `arr1` is not an array of `char`.

Comment: Sorry its not str but it is strcpy()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. copy the character
2. add the terminating null character

code:

```
char arr1[10]="12345";
char arr2[4][4]={"0","-1"};

arr2[1][0] = arr1[1]; /* 1 */
arr2[1][1] = '\0'; /* 2 */
```

Comment: This is not copy , you just assign value :-)

Comment: @ameyCU assigning **is** copying of the value. Why do you think it is not copy?

Comment: why i was not able copy using strcpy() fucntion like strcpy(arr2[1],arr1[1])

Comment: @DurgaPrasad Because `strcpy` requires pointers for each argument, but `arr1[1]` has type `char` and isn't a pointer. It should be invalid value when it is converted to a pointer and dereferencing the converted pointer should lead to Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @MikeCAT But in string if u want to copy something from one pointer another pointer then u require to use strcpy function to copy.  if i we will try to use assign operator then it shows error "Lvalue require". Why it is?

Comment: @DurgaPrasad Not knowint exact answer because I don't see your code that causes the error, maybe because you cannot assign to arrays in C.

Comment: One thing more you assigning null into array at end of index?

Comment: It's surprising, I know, but it is possible to write valid code that is not just stringing together library calls.